# Question regarding compound Poisson random variable

Tags: probability

I have a question regarding compound Poisson random variable.

Let $X:=\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\alpha_i}$ to be a compound Poisson random variable, where $N$ is a Poisson random variable with mean $1$, and $(\alpha_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a family of i.i.d random variables with distribution $\mu$, independent of $N$. Prove that for any $p>0$, $E[|X|^p]<\infty$ if and only if $E[|\alpha_1|^p]<\infty$.

Kindly help as I am new to Probability.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one direction:

- If $p\geqslant1$, then $|X|^p\leqslant N^{p-1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^N|\alpha_i|^p$ hence $E[|X|^p\mid N]\leqslant N^{p}E[|\alpha_1|^p]$.
- If $p\lt1$, then $|X|^p\leqslant\sum\limits_{k=1}^N|\alpha_i|^p$ hence $E[|X|^p\mid N]\leqslant NE[|\alpha_1|^p]$.
- In both cases, $E[|X|^p]\leqslant E[N^q]E[|\alpha_1|^p]$ with $q=\max\{p,1\}$. Since $E[N^q]$ is finite for every positive $q$, if $\alpha_1$ is in $L^p$ then $X$ is in $L^p$.

In the other direction:

- If $N=1$ then $X=\alpha_1$ hence $|X|^p\geqslant|\alpha_1|^p\mathbf 1_{N=1}$ and $E[|X|^p]\geqslant E[|\alpha_1|^p]\,P[N=1]$. Since $P[N=1]$ is positive,  if $X$ is in $L^p$ then $\alpha_1$ is in $L^p$.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. I will like to ask you why $|X|^p\geq|\alpha_1|^p{\bf{1}}_{N=1}$ implies $E[|X|^p]\leq E[|\alpha_1|^p]P[N=1]$. Since we are taking the integration, why can you move the indicator function outside?

Comment: The second inequality should be $\geq$. Apologies for the typo.

Comment: Can I write the second part in this way: $|\alpha_i|^p\leq |X|^p{\bf{1}}_{N=1}$

Comment: "why can you move the indicator function outside?" Because $\alpha_1$ and $N$ are independent. "Can I write the second part in this way" No you cannot, since the pointwise inequality you suggest is obviously wrong.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the explanation. Ya, my inequality is wrong because for those N not equal to 1, the inequality is false.